# Maximum allowable AC voltage for film capacitors as a function of frequency

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, maximum-ratings, power-dissipation, metal-film

For a project that I'm working on, I would like to generate an oscillating magnetic field. In order to achieve this, I would like to create a series LC circuit with multiple film capacitors in series to the coil oscillating at approximately 1kHz (the voltage across the series capacitance would be around 3kV.)

I would like to estimate what the maximum permissible amplitude for a sinusoidally oscillating voltage at 1kHz across the [following film capacitor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kemet/C4AF3BU4100T1YK/14312475) would be. The voltage should be applied to the capacitor for approximately 10 minutes at a time.

The datasheet of the capacitor only states an AC rated voltage of 400V. According to the [general technical information from TDK](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/530754/480aeb04c789e45ef5bb9681513474ba/pdf-generaltechnicalinformation.pdf) this voltage is typically meant for a 50Hz (see chapter 3.2 of the document) sine wave. This document also gives the following graph depicting the mechanisms that limit the AC voltage as a function of frequency:

[image]

If I understand correctly, at 50Hz and 1kHz, we should be in region "b", e.g. the current is limited by thermal power dissipation in the capacitor. According to the graph, in this region we should have:

$$ \frac{\hat{V}_{max,f_0}}{\hat{V}_{max,f_1}} = (\frac{f_0}{f_1})^{-\frac{3}{4}} $$

and therefore

$$ \hat{V}_{max,1kHz} = (\frac{1000Hz}{50Hz})^{-\frac{3}{4}} \cdot \hat{V}_{max,50Hz}\approx 0.1\hat{V}_{max,50Hz} $$

Do you think that this estimate is correct, e.g. at 1kHz, the maximum allowable AC voltage \$\hat{V}_{max,1kHz}\$ is only around 10% of the maximum allowable AC voltage at 50 Hz \$\hat{V}_{max,50Hz}\$ for film capacitors?

Is there maybe a better alternative to implement such an oscillating capacitor other than film capcaitors in series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I would like to estimate what the maximum permissible amplitude for a
> sinusoidal oscillating voltage at 1kHz across the following film
> capacitor would be.*

No need to estimate it because, if you go to the [Kemet site](https://ksim3.kemet.com/capacitor-simulation?pn=C4AF3BU4100T1YK) they have interactive graphs: -

[image]

The graph above is for your capacitor; namely the C4AF3BU4100T1YK you linked to the digikey page in your question. So, it's good for 400 volts RMS at 1 kHz

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question!